# SQL - case that returns repeated values ​in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get 'more' in the sql query for all values ​​repeated in the table for the 'CE.TITLE' column. I made a short CASE but it ends with a mistake.

```
CASE
    WHEN having count(CE.TITLE) > 1
    THEN 'More'
    ELSE 'ok'
END as more than one job

Error:
ORA-0093: missing expression
0036. 0000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 46 Column: 10
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help -- simplify your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `having` is not appropriate:

```
(CASE WHEN count(CE.TITLE) > 1
      THEN 'More'
      ELSE 'ok'
 END) as more_than_one_job
```

This fixes the syntax error and assumes the overall query is an aggregation query.  If not, you can use window functions (in MySQL 8+).  I am guessing the logic you really want is:

```
(CASE WHEN count(*) over (partition by CE.TITLE) > 1
      THEN 'More'
      ELSE 'ok'
 END) as more_than_one_job
```

In earlier versions, you can use a correlated subquery.  My preference would be:

```
(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM ce ce2
                   WHERE ce2.title = ce.title AND
                         ce2.id <> ce.id
                  )
      THEN 'More'
      ELSE 'ok'
 END) as more_than_one_job
```

Comment: SELECT
    AAA,
    BBB,
    CCC,
    count(*) over (partition by TITLE)
FROM 
    my_tabel
WHERE
    AAA IS NOT NULL
    AND BBB = 'SOMETHING'
    AND (count(*) over (partition by TITLE)) > 1
;

Thank you for your response. How to apply a similar solution in the where clause. 
Is it possible?

Comment: @MaddieGraham . . . You would need a subquery or CTE if you want to filter on the number.  You might want to ask another question with sample data and desired results, explaining exactly what you want to do.